# Unable to allocate URBs error on USB Wi-Fi Netgear WNDA3200

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-modem

I bought Wi-Fi USB dongle Netgear WNDA3200.
It's based on [Atheros AR7010+AR9280](http://www.atheros.com/networking/technology.php?nav1=88&product=78) chipset and it is supported by [ath9k_htc](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k_htc/) driver.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with kernel 3.2.0-30-generic (x86_64).
This device is recognized correctly and `lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 008 Device 005: ID 0846:9018 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3200 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Atheros AR7010+AR9280]
```

But `dmesg` shows error:

```
usb 8-1: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: htc_7010.fw, size: 72992
usb 8-1: ath9k_htc: Unable to allocate URBs
ath9k_htc: probe of 8-1:1.0 failed with error -22
usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
```

There are 3 firmware files in my /lib/firmware

```
ar7010_1_1.fw
ar7010.fw
htc_7010.fw
```

How to ger rid of error: **Unable to allocate URBs**?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.10 "Unable to allocate URBs" error disappeared and Netgear WNDA3200 is working fine.